# real_ip_header doesn't seem to change the client IP

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make `allow` and `deny` work on the `X-Real-IP` header value.

```
server {

  # ...

  real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
  set_real_ip_from [an-ipv6-addr];
  set_real_ip_from [an-ipv4-addr];

  # ...

  location /foobar {
    allow [an-ipv6-addr];
    allow [an-ipv4-addr];
    deny all;
  }
}
```

... but access to `/foobar` is denied, even if the `X-Real-IP` value is one of `[an-ipv6-addr]` or `[an-ipv4-addr]` (I can confirm that by logging `$http_x_real_ip` for each request).

Shouldn't `real_ip_header` set the IP `allow` and `deny` are working from?